# Change Random Element of a Matrix with small Restriction

Tags: arrays, matlab, random, vector, matrix

I have a Vector 1xm, ShortMemory (SM), and a Matrix nxm, Agenda (AG). 
SM only have positive integers and zeros.
Each column of AG only has one element equal to 1 and all the other elements of the same column equal to 0.

My objective is changing the position of the number 1 from a randomly choosen column from AG. The problem is that only columns that have a corresponding 0 in SM can be changed.

Example:

```
SM = [1 0 2];
AG = [1 1 0 ; 0 0 1 ; 0 0 0];
```

Randomly Generated number here

```
RandomColumn = 2;
```

The possible outcomes would be

```
AG = [1 0 0 ; 0 1 1 ; 0 0 0]; or AG = [1 0 0; 0 0 1 ; 0 1 0]; or AG = [1 1 0 ; 0 0 1 ; 0 0 0];
```

The Line that gets the 1 is also random but that's easy to do

I could do it by just getting random numbers between 1 and m but m can be very big in my problem and the number of zeros can be very small too, so it could potentially take alot of time. I could also do it with a cycle but it's Matlab and this is embeded on double cycle already.

Thanks

edit: Added commentary to the code for clarity.

edit: Corrected an error on possible outcome

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is difficult to understand. In the example `AG` what is the pattern with which you change column 2 in the case that a 0 exists in `SM(2)`? You have given 2 examples but I dont get the pattern.

Comment: why are there two ones in the third column of second `AG`?

Comment: The pattern is random too, in my progam I choose a random line, set the RandomColumn to all 0's, and then set the #randomline of that column to 1, the line can be the same as it was before.
You can only have 1 '1' per column but each line can have as many as you want in AG.

Comment: Quote: <<You can only have 1 '1' per column>>, but second AG has two ones in third column.

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro My solution has a bug, wait till I edit it.

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro The code is now correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution is based on following assumptions:

1. Objective is changing the position of the number 1 from a randomly choosen column from AG.
2. Only columns that have a corresponding 0 in SM can be changed.

Solution:

```
% input
SM = [1 0 2]
AG = [1 1 0 ; 0 0 1 ; 0 0 0]

% generating random column according to assumptions 1 and 2
RandomColumn1 = 1:size(AG,2);
RandomColumn1(SM~=0)=[];
RandomColumn1=RandomColumn1(randperm(length(RandomColumn1)));
RandomColumn=RandomColumn1(1);

% storing the current randomly chosen column before changing
tempColumn=AG(:,RandomColumn);

% shuffling the position of 1
AG(:,RandomColumn)=AG(randperm(size(AG,1)),RandomColumn);

% following checks if the column has remained same after shuffling. This while loop should execute (extremely) rarely.
while tempColumn==AG(:,RandomColumn)
   tempColumn=AG(:,RandomColumn);
   AG(:,RandomColumn)=AG(randperm(size(AG,1)),RandomColumn);
end
AG
```

Comment: `AG(:,RandomColumn)=AG(randperm(size(AG,1)),RandomColumn);`
missing a ) and dimension mismatch

Comment: are you sure? runs perfectly for me, if I copy-paste

Comment: yeah I think i copied it b4 you edited 3 min to test is reasonable :D